# Streaming data from Amazon S3 using smart_open causing TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to stream data from a large text file sitting in Amazon S3 to my AWS Lambda, I am using smart_open to accomplish that, here's my test code -

```
import smart_open

def stream_data():
    my_bucket = 'monkey-business-dev'
    my_key = 'incoming_monkey_data/banana/banana'
    uri = 's3://{}/{}'.format(my_bucket, my_key)
    total_lines = 0
    total_records = 0
    for line in smart_open.smart_open(uri):
        total_records += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream_data()
```

I am using Python3x and I am facing this exception -

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odo/backends/pandas.py:94: FutureWarning: pandas.tslib is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
You can access NaTType as type(pandas.NaT)
  @convert.register((pd.Timestamp, pd.Timedelta), (pd.tslib.NaTType, type(None)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/monkey_lambda/datastream_from_s3.py", line 16, in <module>
    stream_data()
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/monkey_lambda/datastream_from_s3.py", line 11, in stream_data
    for line in smart_open.smart_open(uri):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 163, in smart_open
    bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket(parsed_uri.bucket_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 509, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 528, in head_bucket
    response = self.make_request('HEAD', bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 671, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 913, in _mexe
    self.is_secure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 705, in get_http_connection
    return self.new_http_connection(host, port, is_secure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 747, in new_http_connection
    connection = self.proxy_ssl(host, is_secure and 443 or 80)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 796, in proxy_ssl
    sock.sendall("CONNECT %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % host)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and I tried to convert it to `utf-8` but then I get following error -

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odo/backends/pandas.py:94: FutureWarning: pandas.tslib is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
You can access NaTType as type(pandas.NaT)
  @convert.register((pd.Timestamp, pd.Timedelta), (pd.tslib.NaTType, type(None)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxx/PycharmProjects/monkey_lambda/datastream_from_s3.py", line 16, in <module>
    stream_data()
  File "/Users/xxxxx/PycharmProjects/monkey_lambda/datastream_from_s3.py", line 11, in stream_data
    for line in smart_open.smart_open(uri.encode()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 208, in smart_open
    raise TypeError('don\'t know how to handle uri %s' % repr(uri))
TypeError: don't know how to handle uri b's3://monkey-business-dev/incoming_monkey_data/banana/banana'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late and you might already have this figured out, but here are the two problems with what you are doing:
You are trying to read a directory using smart_open. Here's what you should do:
For example, if your filename is "test.txt":

```
my_bucket = 'monkey-business-dev'
my_key = 'incoming_monkey_data/banana/banana'
my_file = 'test.txt'
uri = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(my_bucket, my_key, my_file)
file = smart_open.smart_open(uri, encoding="utf-8")
content = file.read()
content_list = content.split("\n")
total_lines = len(content_list)
return total_lines
```

Upvote this answer if it helps. Thanks.